# Create filter for most recent date using combined columns

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, embedding

I have created a filtering application in Access that references four simple tables:

```
Employee: Emp_ID, FirstName, LastName 
Skill: Skill_ID, SkillName, SkillDescription, SkillGroup
Employee_Skill: Entry_ID, Emp_ID, Skill_ID, LevelofExperience, Dateupdated
SkillGroupName:SkillGroup_ID SkillGroupName`
```

Basically the idea of this database is to track employee skills and how the level of experience improves (or not!) over time. The problem I am facing is that I want the application to filter by the most recently updated combination of Skill and Employee. I have found the query that will allow for me to use the two columns as a distinct entity:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Emp_ID, Skill_ID FROM Employee_Skill
WHERE (SELECT MAX(DateUpdated)From Employee_Skill);
```

And it works perfectly on its own, but I don't know how to incorporate it either into my main query, which simply joins together the necessary columns for an easier end user experience. It does not visibly show `Emp_ID` or `Skill_ID`. It also doesn't in the VBA for the application. (-1 = Include all History; 0 = Only include most updated.)

Update:
I have been able to select the distinct combination of Employee and Skill through my main query by doing this:

```
SELECT 
 Employee.FirstName, 
 Employee.LastName, 
 Max(Employee_Skill.LevelOfExperience) AS LevelOfExperience, 
 Skill.SkillName, 
 Max(Employee_Skill.DateUpdated) AS DateUpdated, 
 Max(SkillGroup.SkillGroupName) AS SkillGroupName
FROM 
 SkillGroup INNER JOIN 
 (Skill INNER JOIN 
  (Employee INNER JOIN 
   Employee_Skill ON 
   Employee.Emp_ID = Employee_Skill.Emp_ID) ON 
  Skill.Skill_ID = Employee_Skill.Skill_ID) ON 
 SkillGroup.SkillGroup_ID = Skill.SkillGroup
WHERE 
 Employee.Active=True
GROUP BY 
 Employee.FirstName, 
 Employee.LastName, 
 Skill.SkillName
ORDER BY 
 Max(Employee_Skill.LevelOfExperience) DESC;
```

However, my forms and reports built on this query are stuck with only the option of seeing the most updated version. I am really hoping to have a dynamic form that removes the constraints as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're doing with `Max(Employee_Skill.LevelOfExperience)` or `Max(SkillGroup.SkillGroupName)` but I think you need to stick with querying for the detail rows and then include another column marking the `Max(Employee_Skill.DateUpdated)` filter, like:

```
SELECT 
 Employee.FirstName, 
 Employee.LastName, 
 Employee_Skill.LevelOfExperience, 
 Skill.SkillName, 
 Employee_Skill.DateUpdated, 
 SkillGroup.SkillGroupName,
 iif(max_dateUpdated=dateupdated,1,0) as is_max_DateUpdated
FROM 
 SkillGroup INNER JOIN 
 (Skill INNER JOIN 
  (Employee INNER JOIN 
   Employee_Skill ON 
   Employee.Emp_ID = Employee_Skill.Emp_ID) ON 
  Skill.Skill_ID = Employee_Skill.Skill_ID) ON 
 SkillGroup.SkillGroup_ID = Skill.SkillGroup inner join
 (select  
   empID,
   max(dateupdated) as max_dateUpdated 
  from
   Employee_Skill
  group by 
   empID) mx on
  Employee.empID = mx.empID
WHERE 
 Employee.Active=True
```